# Wildfly resource adapter for Websphere MQ connection definition

Tags: java, ibm-mq, wildfly

I am trying to connect to Websphere MQ from Wildfly 9, For this I have added a resource adapter in standalone-full.xml

I am getting this error:

> 16:03:58,387 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC
>   service thread 1-1) IJ020017: Invalid archive:
>   file:/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp755b6e876dab356a/
>   content-5c7db729978cd59e/contents/ 16:03:58,389 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020001: Required license terms for
>   file:/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp755b
>   6e876dab356a/content-5c7db729978cd59e/contents/ 16:03:58,395 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020009: Invalid connection definition with class-name:
>   javax.jms.ConnectionFactory 16:03:58,399 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020009: Invalid connection definition with class-name:
>   javax.jms.ConnectionFactory 16:03:58,400 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020009: Invalid connection definition with class-name:
>   javax.jms.ConnectionFactory 16:03:58,448 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   WFLYJCA0006: Registered admin object at java:jboss/contm/ToConTM
>   16:03:58,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0006: Registered admin object at
>   java:jboss/contm/FromConTM 16:03:58,452 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020017: Invalid archive:
>   file:/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp755b6e876dab35
>   6a/content-5c7db729978cd59e/contents/ 16:03:58,454 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) IJ020002: Deployed:
>   file:/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp755b6e876dab356a/cont
>   ent-5c7db729978cd59e/contents/ 16:03:58,455 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA AdminObject [java:jboss/contm/ToConTM]
>   16:03:58,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA AdminObject
>   [java:jboss/contm/FromConTM]

my resource adpater looks like this:

```
<resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
  <archive>
  wmq.jmsra.rar
  </archive>
  <connection-definitions>
  <connection-definition class-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/contm/jmsConnectionFactory" pool-name="jmsConnectionFactory">             

  </connection-definition>
  </connection-definitions>
  <admin-objects>
  <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/contm/FromConTM" use-java-context="true" pool-name="FromConTM">
  <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
  devel.queue.manager
  </config-property>
  <config-property name="baseQueueName">
  NewQueue2
  </config-property>
  </admin-object>
  <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/contm/ToConTM" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ToConTM">
  <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
  devel.queue.manager
  </config-property>
  <config-property name="baseQueueName">
  NewQueue1
  </config-property>
  </admin-object>
  </admin-objects>
  </resource-adapter>
```

I have added config properties and removed them added differen properties that might seem useful like use-java-context="true" pool-name="jmsConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true" removed them or made them false, changed the jndi name but it keeps on giving me the same . i have other connection definitions in the standalone-full.xml but they are all bound correctly without issues.

Can any one see what I am missing in this case. If i use XATransaction and class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl"

It is fine.. but not with the one above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original configs i was given were old and perhaps worked at that time. with WF9 my setup needs to be as below

```
<connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/ctm/ConnectionFactory" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
```

tested this and it works fine as previously some how they were using javax.jms.ConnectionFactory